# Monitor not detected on nVidia eGPU

Tags: windows, display, gpu, vga, dvi

I have a ThinkPad W540 laptop which has an ExpressCard 2.0 slot. I took advantage of it and built my own eGPU setup, using a PE4L 2.1b adapter, and an nVidia GeForce 750Ti card from EVGA. Usually when I want to play games suing the eGPU, I have my laptop docked in the ThinkPad UltraDock to which I normally have connected 2 monitors using DVI.

Now, because disconnecting cables from both the monitors, and the docking station is a bit cumbersome, I decided to connect a VGA cable to one of the monitors (thus filling all of the slots of the monitor), and connect that to the external GPU using the DVI to VGA adapter supplied by EVGA in the box. I do not mind the slight quality loss by taking the analogue route, and I rather prefer the convenience of not having to unplug things.

When I connect the eGPU and boot the laptop, the graphics card is powered, and perfectly detected in Device Manager. Yet, the monitor does not receive a signal on VGA. If I install the latest nVidia driver, the monitor gets detected, and from thereon everything works perfect. Until I restart, after which the monitor is absent again, and I have to repeat installing the nVidia drivers (using setup.exe).

My guess is that the monitor receives the wrong signal (digital) at boot, and because it does not responds properly (expecting analogue), the card decides not to output to it. During driver installation, some magic monitor detection is triggered and the display is identified and works properly. This all because of the cumbersome DVI-I connector.

Does any one have any idea on how to have it detect the monitor's VGA input from boot?

Btw, I am using Windows 10 Pro. Thanks!

Comment: If you skip the docking station, and connected the monitors to the eGPU does it work like you expect?